# Composer update `The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured` error in vagrant

Tags: php, memory, vagrant, composer-php, virtualbox

I got php5.5 with composer installed in a vagrant VirtualBox environment.

When I try any composer's commands the following error appears randomly:

`The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured`

How can I get around this ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It isn't a bug and fix it - To enable the swap you can use for example:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Ref: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Created swapfile with fallocate and swapon fails with invalid argument. Using dd as Alex does above works.

Comment: Solved my problem.
Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to know how to revert this, in case you only want temporary changes.

Comment: Worked for me as is

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes swap file has not enough memory for composer update, so create a new one:

(assuming existing /swapfile has 2G, create new /swapfile1 with 8G of your drive space)

```
$ sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile1
$ sudo chmod 600 /swapfile1

$ sudo mkswap /swapfile1
$ sudo swapon /swapfile1
```

after composer updated, you can remove it and keep only initial file:

```
$ sudo swapoff /swapfile1
$ sudo rm /swapfile1
```

Answer (score 6):

[This thread](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1898) suggest that their will not be any fix for that.

Here are two workarounds. You can use each separately or both at the same time.

#### 1st workaround: increase memory limit for the command

In the vagrant machine. Increase the php memory limit for the current command. Run:

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G /path/to/composer update
```

#### 2nd workaround: increase guest machine memory

Add this configuration to your vagrant file, so you can temporary increase allocated memory:

```
$MEMORY = ENV.has_key?('VM_MEMORY') ? ENV['VM_MEMORY'] : "512"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    [...]
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        [...]
        v.memory = $MEMORY
        [...]
    end
    [...]
end
```

Then reload your vagrant machine as follow: `VM_MEMORY=2048 vagrant reload`

Then, in your vagrant machine, run `composer update`.

Comment: Altering the VMs memory sorted the issue for me. Only increasing PHP's memory limit didn't do the trick. Swap is not recommended if you have an SSD as it's damaging.

Comment: The php -dmemory_limit=2 command worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

this solved my problem:

```sh
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024  
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

this can be temproray useful and solve the issu. to permanently add to swap follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

to see free memory on your device: `free -m`

[source](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Go to php.ini file and update the 
memory_limit to 512MB or 1G